# Flutter, confusion with Network assets

Tags: flutter, assets, assetslibrary

Suppose, I have a product page or a carousel and that fetches network data,

let us discuss the simplest example with the carousel image data retrieved from Image.network.

My question is if I provide the image URLS from a [List], and publish the app. then if I had any need in future to change the Images as well as the Img URLs in that [List] then for that simple task should I have to edit the code recompile and reupload the app?

This doesn't seem Right there must be a better way like a CSV or Sheet file.

If anyone aware of this please help me with a comprehensive guide.

Comment: Why don't you persist them in DB? Within their respective product data..

Comment: For that you have to create database where you can upload data and fetch it where and whenever you want.

Comment: So here, all data are static? No database has been linked?

Comment: In that case, you shall try `Firebase Remote Config`, if that suits for your model.. https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config

Comment: Hello, MTM and Amit, Yes I want to create a dynamically linked thing. As I read firebase is a paid service though I didn't understand all the terminologies used in the pricing sheet still I want to do it without being dependent on firebase. So If you people let me know of linking  things as I intended from my Personal server or google drive how can I do that with a Sheet or Csv without hardcoding. Thank you for your responses. Also being new to this dev operations I am not aware of  Database like things, still I will try to gather knowledge about that.